# for loop not incrementing counter in gcc

Tags: c

I'm using gcc 4.9.2 and have a program to print sum of 4th powers of N numbers.

I have written the program but the sum always printed out is 4th power of the number entered and not the sum.
I think it is a problem with the counter but don't know what.

```
if(n>0 && n<=40)
{
   for(c=0;c<=n;c++)
   {
       s=0;
       s=s+c*c*c*c;
   }
   printf("%d",s);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you set

```
s=0;
```

inside the loop.

Put it outside the for loop.

```
if(n>0 && n<=40)
{
   s=0;
   for(c=0;c<=n;c++)
   {
       s=s+c*c*c*c;
   }
   printf("%d",s);
}
```

BTW:
The for-loop can be changed to:

```
   for(c=1;c<=n;c++)
```

because the value c=0 doesn't change anything.